# TortoiseSVN client side pre-commit hook authentication failure

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am working on a client side pre-commit hook, my problem is that if the users didn't save their credentials, the pre-commit hook just hangs and when I close the hook's cmd the commit window returns authentication failure, if I retry without the hook it shows the authentication dialog asking for the username/password and commits normally. Why doesn't the SVN show the authentication dialog before calling the hook? and how can I force it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't the SVN show the authentication dialog before calling the hook?

Because **TortoiseSVN** (sic!) doesn't communicate with free-form app, which you use as client-side pre-commit  hook. If you have to use some svn-commands with authenticated access in these hook (why, BTW?), **you must add** command-line options to used commands